# Iterating through CSV::Rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, csv

I'm going to preface that I'm still learning ruby.

I'm writing a script to parse a .csv and identify possible duplicate records in the data-set.

I have a .csv file with headers, so I'm parsing the data so that I can access each row using a header title as such:

```rb
@contact_table = CSV.parse(File.read("app/data/file.csv"), headers: true)

# Prints all last names in table
puts contact_table['last_name']
```

I'm trying to iterate over each row in the table and identify if the last name I'm currently iterating over is similar to the next last name, but I'm having trouble doing this. I guess the way I'm handling it is as if it's an array, but I checked the type and it's a CSV::Row.

example (this doesn't work):

```rb
@contact_table.each_with_index do |c, i|
  puts "first contact is #{c['last_name']}, second contact is #{c[i + 1]['last_name']}"
end
```

I realized this doesn't work like this because the table isn't an array, it's a CSV::Row like I previously mentioned. Is there any method that can achieve this? I'm really blanking right now.

My csv looks something like this:

```
id,first_name,last_name,company,email,address1,address2,zip,city,state_long,state,phone
1,Donalt,Canter,Gottlieb Group,dcanter0@nydailynews.com,9 Homewood Alley,,50335,Des Moines,Iowa,IA,515-601-4495
2,Daphene,McArthur,"West, Schimmel and Rath",dmcarthur1@twitter.com,43 Grover Parkway,,30311,Atlanta,Georgia,GA,770-271-7837
```

Answer (score 3):

`@contact_table` should be a `CSV::Table` which is a collection of `CSV::Row`s so in this:

```
@contact_table.each_with_index do |c, i|
  ...
end
```

`c` is a `CSV::Row`. That's why `c['last_name']` works. The problem is that here:

```
c[i + 1]['last_name']
```

you're looking at `c` (a single row) instead of `@contact_table`, if you said:

```
@contact_table[i + 1]['last_name']
```

then you'd get the next last name or, when `c` is the last row, an exception because `@contact_table[i+1]` will be `nil`.

Also, inside the iteration, `c` is the *current* (or `(i+1)`th) row and won't always be the first.

Comment: Thanks! I feel so stupid that I overlooked this, haha. My next question is that when I do this,  I get this error:

no implicit conversion of String into Integer

for this line:
  puts "first contact is #{c['last_name']}, second contact is #{contact_table[i + 1]['last_name']}". Any ideas? I'm still a bit lost.

Comment: I believed at first it was the latter. but now I can't even get `c['last_name']` to print out anything without raising that error. I'll update the question with a sample of the .csv.

Comment: Oh my gosh! I deleted `headers: true` by accident. Lol, I'm sorry. I'm so frazzled. However, I added in your code and now have a "undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass" error instead. My code looks like this: 
```@contact_table.each_with_index do |c, i|
  puts "last names are #{c['last_name']}"
  puts "next last name is #{@contact_table[i + 1]['last_name']}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What is your use case for this? Seems like a school project?

I recommend [for_each](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-foreach) instead of parse (see [this comparison](https://dalibornasevic.com/posts/68-processing-large-csv-files-with-ruby)). I would probably use a [Set](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.4/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) for this.

- Create a Set outside of the scope of parsing the file (i.e., above the parsing code). Let's call it `rows`.
- Call `rows.include?(row)` during each iteration while parsing the file

  - If `true`, then you know you have a duplicate
  - If false, then call `rows.add(row)` to add the new row to the set

You could also just fill your set with an individual value from a column that must be distinct (e.g., `row.field(:some_column_name)`), such as email or phone number, and do the same inclusion check for that.

(If this is for a real app, please don't do this. Use model [validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html) instead.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`#read`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read) instead of [`#parse`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-parse) and do something like this:

```
require 'csv'
LASTNAME_INDEX = 2
data = CSV.read('data.csv')

data[1..-1].each_with_index do |row, index|
  puts "Contact number #{index + 1} has the following last name : #{row[LASTNAME_INDEX]}"
end

#~> Contact number 1 has the following last name : Canter
#~> Contact number 2 has the following last name : McArthur
```